# Set up network with static IP and wpa_supplicant on Debian

Tags: debian, networking, wpa-supplicant

On Debian, I am trying to set up my network to use ad-hoc mode with a static IP address. I also want wpa_supplicant to be running so that I can scan use it to scan for WiFi networks in range.

To get the ad-hoc network with static IP address working I modified the `/etc/network/interfaces` file so that it looks like this:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet dhcp

auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
  address 192.168.1.1
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  wireless-channel 1
  wireless-essid MyNetworkName
  wireless-mode ad-hoc
```

But with this configuration, if I try to access `wpa_supplicant` using `wpa_cli` I get an error which indicates that wpa_supplicant is not running. Is there something I can add to this configuration that will allow wpa_supplicant to start up but not be used to connect up to a network?

I suppose I could just use `iwlist scan` to find the list of available wireless networks in range... but I already have my parsing setup for the output of `wpa_cli scan_results` :)

Comment: Read this https://wiki.debian.org/WPA

Answer (score 2):

`wireless-tools` (i.e. `iwlist`, `iwconfig`, `iwpriv` ...) are prehistoric and should be replaced by invocations of `iw`. The `wireless-` things in `/etc/network/interfaces` are not handled by `wpa_supplicant`, but by those old `wireless-tools`, which ships scripts in `/etc/network/if-*.d/wireless-tools`.

Compare with the script shipped by wpa_supplicant in `/etc/network/if-*.d/wpasupplicant` which are just symlinks to scripts in `/etc/wpa_supplicant/`. They handle options of the form `wpa-*`

To start wpa_supplicant without an active config, just specify an empty configuration file, like ... `/dev/null`. Remember to use the `nl80211` driver, because everything else (including `wext`) is just outdated, but is still the default in the old 1.1 version of `wpa_supplicant` that Debian ships.

```
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
    address 192.168.1.1
    netmask 24
    wpa-conf /dev/null
    wpa-driver nl80211
```

Comment: I'm a little confused by your answer. First of all if I just type `iw`, it is not recognized as a command. Does that mean I am using an older version of Debian? Second you said that /etc/network/interfaces is used to configure the older wireless tools. Does that mean I shouldn't need to use that file at all?  I tried updating my interfaces file above by adding the two lines in the bottom of your answer but I get the following error: `wpa_supplicant: cannot read contents of /dev/null ... exited with error code 1`

Comment: Ok. I installed the iw tools. Unfortunately, it looks like my network adapter doesn't support the nl80211 driver. I am using an Edimax nano usb wifi adapter.

Comment: @PICyourBrain: What old version of Debian are you using ?

Comment: The latest Raspian image for the RaspberryPi

Answer (score 1):

I know, this is quite an old thread, but I came across the same issue and I found a solution for Debian bullseye (on raspberry pi).
The required configuration for having fixed IP addresses has to be made in /etd/dhcpcd.conf

```
interface wlan0
static ip_address=192.168.0.4/24
static ip6_address=xxx:xxx:xxx::x/64
static routers=192.168.0.1
static domain_name_servers=ip.add.rr abc:adbd::1
```

Using this configuration, the ip addresses are set as static ones...